# What is this card game called in English?

Tags: identify-this-game

What is the name of this card game?

you deal out cards between two players, the person that deals gets 8 and the other gets 7. 
You then put all of the cards onto the side with the very last card of the deck facing up.
Player with 8 cards puts down first, it can be any card.
Second player takes a card and then puts down as well.

You have to take a card and put down every time it’s your turn.

In order to score points in the game you have to combine cards together of the same suit only if it’s for example, 345 same suit. Or you can do JJJ, QQQ.

The minimum you can put down is 3 cards.

Cards 3-8 = 5 Pts.
Cards 9-K = 10 Pts.
Card Ace = 15 Pts.
Card 2 = 50 Pts.

In order to take cards from where both players have put down you have to score at least 25 Pts. first.

The goal of the game is to score the most or if lucky to close the game up and catch the person with points in their hand. This game usually goes on for several rounds until one person scores 500 points.

There are more technical rules to this game but I’m trying to summarize. I know the name of this card game from a different country but I do not know the name of it in English (if it even exists).

Can anyone guess?

Comment: So I just looked up rummy and it turns out you can play with more people but with this game it’s just a two player game. And also it says the highest card is a King in rummy but in this game it’s a 2 and there are also no jokers. So I don’t know if this is rummy or just a different variation of it or just another game. Any other ideas on what it could be?

Comment: I'm curious to hear what the answer is!  This sounds like something halfway between a more traditional Rummy game, and one of its offshoots, Canasta.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you  are referring to [Rummy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rummy) or some variation of it

It has many different variants but the crux of the game is draw a card and put one down in order to make sets and runs.

Answer (score -1):

The closest I can find is the Rummy variant 500 Rum (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/500_rum).

Comment: Not sure, to be honest for 500 rum it says the Ace is the highest so who knows it might be a variation. But let me know if you guys find anything with a two being the high card. Appreciate all the answers.